# Json handling in ROBOT

Tags: json, robotframework

I have a Json file in which there is a field which I need to edit and save the file for next usage.

But the field which I need to edit is as shown below,

The value I need to assign fr the field is generated Randomly in run time which i'll be capturing in a variable and pass it to this json specific key "dp" then save the json.

The saved json will be used for REST POST url.

```
            {
                "p": "10",
                "v": 100,
                "vt": [
                    {
                        "dp": "Field to be edited"(integer value) , 
                  ]          
            }
```

Comment: sorry, i dint get u.

Comment: Have you written any code to try and accomplish what you want to do?

Comment: no, i havent tried. As I am using ROBOT framework, i tried to use tool like ace , which changes json in run time.But i need a API inbuilt / the code piece to update a specific key value.

Comment: Do you know how to write code in python, or do you need a solution that doesn't involve writing code?

Comment: You've posted invalid json data in your question. You have an open square bracket, and open curly bracket, then a close square bracket

Comment: I just gave a stucture of code where to highlight the data need to be replaced. This is not actual code i am using. Yes I know to write code in python.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to write a python keyword that can change the value for you. However, you can solve this with robot keywords by performing the following steps:

1. convert the JSON string to a dictionary
2. modify the dictionary
3. convert the dictionary back to a JSON string

#### Convert the JSON string to a dictionary

Python has a module ([json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)) for working with JSON data. You can use the [evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword to convert your JSON string to a python dictionary using the [loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) (load string) method of that module.

Assuming your JSON data is in a robot variable named `${json_string}`, you can convert it to a python dictionary like this:

```
${json}=    evaluate    json.loads('''${json_string}''')    json
```

With the above, `${json}` now holds a reference to a dictionary that contains all of the json data.

#### Modify the dictionary

The [Collections](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html) library that comes with robot has a keyword named [set to dictionary](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Set%20To%20Dictionary) which can be used to set the value of a dictionary element. In this case, you need to change the value of a dictionary nested inside the `vt` element of the JSON object. We can reference that nested dictionary using robot's [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax).

For example:

```
set to dictionary    ${json["vt"]}    dp=the new value
```

With that,  `${json}` now has the new value. However, it is still a python dictionary rather than JSON data, so there's one more step.

#### Convert the dictionary back to JSON

Converting the dictionary back to JSON is the reverse of the first step. Namely, use the [dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) (dump string) method of the json module:

```
${json_string}=    evaluate    json.dumps(${json})    json
```

With that, `${json_string}` will contain a valid JSON string with the modified data.

---

#### Complete example

The following is a complete working example. The JSON string will be printed before and after the substitution of the new value:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${json_string}=    catenate
    ...  {
    ...    "p": "10",
    ...    "v": 100,
    ...    "vt": {
    ...            "dp": "Field to be edited"
    ...          }
    ...  }

    log to console       \nOriginal JSON:\n${json_string}
    ${json}=             evaluate        json.loads('''${json_string}''')    json
    set to dictionary    ${json["vt"]}    dp=the new value
    ${json_string}=      evaluate        json.dumps(${json})                 json
    log to console       \nNew JSON string:\n${json_string}
```

Comment: Sorry to hi-jack Bryan, this is similar to a problem I'm soon to tackle.  It seems this could do for my needs, I'm assuming the remove from dictionary keyword preserves json document structure without much intentional thought?  I also assume set to dictionary will update if the key exists already, yet add if it doesn't already exist?  Again apologies for the hi-jack, figured I shouldn't add my own question with this being so closely related

Comment: @shicky: the best way to answer your question is for you to try it and see. Everything you asked, you can easily answer with a couple lines of code.

Comment: this is certainly true Bryan, will hopefully free up some time this week or next and get it done.  Thank you for your input

Comment: works like a charm Bryan, thanks for your extremely clear and well presented example above.  Easy to tweak to my needs

Comment: This is a very good answer. In simple cases you don't even need to use the `json` module because simple JSON structures are also valid in Python and you can just use `| ${json} = | Evaluate | ${json_string} |`. Converting back to string ought to work with `| ${json_string} = | Convert To String | ${json} |`.

Comment: @PekkaKlärck Not quite right since `true` is valid in json but not in Python (must be `True`)

Comment: In this example, how can you use the ordered_pairs_hook on json.loads to preserve the order?

Answer (score 2):

For reading and writing data to and from file I am using OperatingSystem library

```
${json} Get Binary File ${json_path}nameOfJsonFile.json
```

It works for me on API testing, to read .json and POST, like here

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    ExtendedRequestsLibrary 
Library    OperatingSystem
*** Variables ***  
${uri}    https://blabla.com/service/
${json_path}    C:/home/user/project/src/json/
*** Test Cases ***
Robot Test Case  
   Create Session    alias    ${uri}    
   &{headers}  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
   ${json}  Get Binary File  ${json_path}nameOfJsonFile.json
   ${resp}    Post Request    alias    data=${json}    headers=${headers}
   Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
```

Comment: what does the shiftB mean? 
```data=${shiftB}  ```

Comment: In my case it is data regarding beginning of the shift, time, dates     and so on 
                ${shiftB}  Get Binary File  ${json_path}addShiftBeginn.json

Answer (score 0):

For integer values in JSON, the other answers did not work for me.
This worked:

```
${json}=    Catenate    {    "p": "10",    "v": 100,    "vt": {    "dp": "Field to be edited"   }    }
${value}    Set Variable    2    #the value you want
${value}    Convert To Integer    ${value}
${json}=    Evaluate    json.loads('''${json}''')    json
Set To Dictionary    ${json["vt"]}    dp=${value}
${json}=    Evaluate    json.dumps(${json})    json
Log    ${json}
```

Convert To Integer was required, otherwise the value is still in string "${value}"