# Robotframework: How to update JSON field value

Tags: python, json, http, robotframework

I am writing a test with the robot framework.  I am trying to update values in a json field, but I am seeing some odd behavior.

I do a HTTP GET and receive a json.  I check what the value is originally,

```
Log To Console | ${JSON["Components"]["SubComponents"]}
```

which returns

```
valueA
```

Then I try to update the values as below.

```
${JSON["Components"]["SubComponents"]}= | Set Variable | valueB
```

If I log the output this way

```
Log To Console | ${JSON["Components"]["SubComponents"]}
```

I see

```
valueB
```

but if I check this way

```
Log To Console | ${JSON["Components"]}
```

I see

```
{u'SubComponents': valueA, u'MoreComponents': whatever}
```

What is going on and why is it not updating?

I need to update the JSON field so I can do an HTTP PATCH.
I have tried following [Json handling in ROBOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262216/json-handling-in-robot/35272804)
But it doesn't work and I think it has something to do with my JSON file having single quotes.

FYI I am new to json and robotframework

Comment: Where is the Python code, and why are you piping things? You can edit the JSON variable within Python

Comment: The pipe is how the robotframework works.. or you can use two spaces.  All the attempts I've made to edit it within python using Evaluate have failed.. the post I linked to attempts to do that but it doesn't work for me and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: @cricket_007 - the `|` is used as a keyword separator, not the generic pipe we know normally. Can either use a pipe or space separator - matter of preference.

Comment: I have actually found a solution.. If I do `Set To Dictionary | ${JSON["Components"]} | SubComponents=valueB` then I see the proper behavior.. I still would like to know what is going on above and why I see it in one case but not the other.  This is part of the proposed solution in the post I linked to but I was unable to get past the json.load() due to problems so I never got to try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set variables that way. You have to keep reminding yourself that robot is not a programming language. What you've done is that you've created a variable named, literally, `${JSON["Components"]["SubComponents"]}`. You are *not* updating the original `${JSON}` variable.

You can see this if you use the keyword [Log variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Log%20Variables). You'll see this new keyword with a name that looks like a dictionary.

To change the value of a dictionary you will need to use a keyword such as [Set to dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Set%20To%20Dictionary)

For example:

```
set to dictionary    ${JSON["Components"]}   Subcomponents=valueb
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  That makes sense now that I realize it.  It seems a little strange that robot would allow for a variable to be named the same as an entry in a dictionary.. but I'm guessing thats because like you said its not a programming language. -- you must've posted this at the same time I put my comment