# How to match specific string in ROBOT FRAMEWORK using regex?

Tags: regex, testing, automation, robotframework

I am using REST-API for testing
I am stuck where I am checking the response with some specific string.
please refer below info
I got the response from a request is

```
{  
 "clusters":[  
  {  
     "id":10,
     "name":"HP2",
     "status":2,
     "statusDisplay":"HParihar@4info.com",
     "lastModifiedBy":"HParihar@4info.com",
     "lastModifiedTime":"06/08/2017 23:42",
     "sitesAppsCount":0
  },
  {  
     "id":799,
     "name":"Regression_cluster_111_09",
     "status":2,
     "statusDisplay":"admin@4info.net",
     "lastModifiedBy":"admin@4info.net",
     "lastModifiedTime":"07/11/2017 08:19",
     "sitesAppsCount":0
  }
]}
```

and I wanted to match just

```
     "name":"Regression_cluster_111_09",
     "status":2,
     "statusDisplay":"admin@4info.net",
     "sitesAppsCount":0
```

right side values I'll be keeping as hard coded.
any guesses?

Comment: I am not sure what the question is. Where do you want to use regex?

Comment: in robot testing framework

Comment: More specifically, what are you trying to match?

Comment: I am checking those 4 parameters are in response or not.

Comment: if you are doing that, check with json. see if the jsonobject holds the four keys.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are only checking those 4 parameters are in response or not.

Do no use regex for this.

Use jsonObject's find key/value feature.

Check whether the values to the keys are there.

If key/value is null, the parameter is not in response.

Comment: Take a look at here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262216/json-handling-in-robot

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer 
I used the following regex

```
"name":"Regression_cluster_111_09","status":2,"statusDisplay":"admin@4info.net","lastModifiedBy":"[a-z]+@[0-9a-z]+\.[a-z]+","lastModifiedTime":"[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}\ [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}","sitesAppsCount":0
```

or I can simply use

```
"name":"Regression_cluster_111_09","status":2,"statusDisplay":"admin@4info.net",.+"sitesAppsCount":0
```

thank you all