# How to get value from JSON list within Robot Framework?

Tags: python, json, robotframework

As part of verification in Robot Framework, I have following data (stored as `${response}`) as get request response:

```
{
    "interfaces": [
        {
            "name": "eth0",
            "status": "ready",
            "macAddress": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "ipv4": {
                "mode": "DHCP",
                "address": "127.0.0.1",
                "mask": "255.255.255.0",
            },
            "ipv6": {
                "mode": "DISABLED",
                "addresses": [],
                "gateway": "",
            }
        }
    ],
    "result": 0
}
```

And I would like to get value of key `ipv4` and compare it with predefined value. I tried to use it out of `HttpLibrary.HTTP` as this will be deprecated for Robot Framework 3.1 so I would like to use `Evaluate`.
Will it be possible within Robot Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json handling in ROBOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262216/json-handling-in-robot)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the variable `${response}` is a response object - vs just a string, the content of the payload - the most straightforward way is to call its `json()` method, which returns the payload as parsed dictionary:

```
${the data}=    Evaluate    ${response.json()}
```

Another way is to parse the payload with `json.loads()` yourself, passing the `.content` attribute that stores it (this is pretty much what the `.json()` does internally):

```
${the data}=    Evaluate    json.loads(${response.content})    json
```

And if that variable `${response}` is a string, the actual payload, then just pass it to `json.loads()`:

```
${the data}=    Evaluate    json.loads($response)    json
```

Now that you have the data as a regular dictionary, do your verifications the normal way:

```
Should Be Equal    ${the data['interfaces'][0]['ipv4']}    ${your predefined dictionary}
```

Comment: I get "No keyword with 'Evaluate ...' found." It seems like everyone who gives an answer about robot framework leaves out the part that would make their answer work.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `Evaluate` is not recognised, it's a built-in keyword, always available for usage. Are you sure you have 2 or more spaces between it & the 1st argument? If it's just one, the whole string will be parsed as the keyword name & will lead to such exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you're needing?

```
jsonObj = {
    "interfaces": [
        {
            "name": "eth0",
            "status": "ready",
            "macAddress": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "ipv4": {
                "mode": "DHCP",
                "address": "127.0.0.1",
                "mask": "255.255.255.0",
            },
            "ipv6": {
                "mode": "DISABLED",
                "addresses": [],
                "gateway": "",
            }
        }
    ],
    "result": 0
}

ipv6 = jsonObj['interfaces'][0]['ipv6']

print (ipv6)
```

**Output:**

```
{'mode': 'DISABLED', 'addresses': [], 'gateway': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just put this way and works:

```
${response.json()['data'][1]['b1_YDESCRI']}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know Robot Framework but if you want to manipulate JSON, you can use the built-in lib json.

```py
import json

data = json.loads(response)

ipv4 = data['interfaces'][0]['ipv4']
```

Comment: Don't answer the question if you're not going to answer the question.